# Exception thrown when hive jdbc code tries to do a map-reduce

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, cloudera, beeline

I have connected to ThriftServer1 using JDBC.(It is a Cloudier cluster , 4.7). When I try to run any query which does not require a map reduce job to be run, the program executes successfully . But when the concerned query requires a map-reduce job, it fails with the exception which I have pasted below.

**For example:**

```
Query1: select * from related.some_table limit 1
=>SUCCESS

Query2: select count(*) from  related.some_table
=>FAILED
```

**Please note:** both the queries run successfully from the Hive CLI. Query 2 fails only when run from within the program.

I have also tried to add the conf directory under HIVE to the class path while running the program. But to no avail.

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.executeImmediate(HivePreparedStatement.java:177)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.executeQuery